# Docker-compose: Mount a volume only in the first container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to run a MariaDB Galera Cluster, where each node is a docker container, but MariaDB GC need a master node at start to initialize the database.

I'd like to choose the master container by mounting a file as a volume in the container, with a script at start which check for this file. So I need docker-compose to mount the file only for the first container launched and not for the container created by doing docker-compose scale.

Is it possible ?

Comment: can you elaborate, post your Dockerfiles, your build and run commands and anything else useful...?

Comment: I reformulated, hope you understand better my problem ;)

Comment: the `docker run` command accepts volumes and environment variables, I guess you can play with a file on a volume, where you write something like "first container launched", and you can also read this file in order to check.the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run , and you can also use `docker inspect` to see if a container has a volume mounted, the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#inspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is not directly possible; when using `docker-compose scale` you will get a suite of identical containers.  You have several options available for selecting a primary node for your Galera cluster.  Here are two; there are undoubtedly others:

### Explicit primary

Have the primary be a single-instance container in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, and only scale the secondary containers.

```
galera_primary:
    image: myimage
    command: command_to_start_galera_master

galera_secondary:
  image: myimage
  links:
    - galera_primary
  command: command_to_start_galera_worker
```

### Dynamic primary

If you're willing to write some code, you could probably use [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) to perform master election, probably by taking advantage of the ability to [atomically create keys](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/2.0.8/api.html#atomic-compare-and-swap).

I don't have an example of this handy, but the process should be relatively simple:

- Each node attempts to create a particular key in etcd
- The node that succeeds is the master
- Other nodes can query etcd for the address of the master

Comment: I did the first solution , but the problem is that I want only one node when I do docker-compose up, is there anyway to not launch the secondary target when doing docker-compose up ?

Comment: Maybe just run `docker-compose up galera_primary` in that case?

Comment: Well, there are other containers than mariadb that need to be launched

Comment: I guess the second solution I suggested would work better, then, since it will work for 1 or > 1 containers.